# Setup Kubernetes (version 1.18) cluster on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I am trying to setup Kubernetes on AWS EC2 there are writeups from this website which is wonderful

https://itnext.io/kubernetes-part-2-a-cluster-set-up-on-aws-with-aws-cloud-provider-and-aws-loadbalancer-f02c3509f2c2

I used the following config file for "kubeadm init"

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "aws"
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "aws"
```

I got an error message saying that aws has been depreciated

I used the same file with the cloud-provider changed to "openstack"

Still I am getting errors; looks like the new version of Kubernetes I need to use another parameter "cloud-config" which has the configuration

Can anyone help me on how this needs to be done and how I can successfully configure a k8 cluster using EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion provided I installed the Kubernetes cluster using kops. The [Full instructions can be found here](https://shiva-data-guru.blogspot.com/2020/05/create-your-own-kubernetes-cluster-on.html)

Answer (score 1):

Referring from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) You can use below config for AWS.

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "openstack"
    cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.13.0
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "openstack"
    cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
  extraVolumes:
  - name: cloud
    hostPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
    mountPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "openstack"
    cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
  extraVolumes:
  - name: cloud
    hostPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
    mountPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
```

And then you can do `kubeadm init --config=kubeadm-config.yml`

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/02/07/deploying-external-openstack-cloud-provider-with-kubeadm/

You could avoid all of these if you just used [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) to install kubernetes on AWS.

Comment: Yes, I could find that; but what is the contents of /etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf

Looking at the second link you have provided, I can see the contents of the stack for openstack; how would this be for aws cloud

Comment: can you tell me what is the reason that you wan to have a cloud provider config?

Comment: I am trying to setup a k8 cluster using EC2

Comment: you may use Kops for that instead of kubeadm

Comment: and I want to allocate storage from AWS EBS Volumes

Comment: I am running into problems with kops too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296806/create-kubernetes-ec2-cluster-on-aws-using-kops